# Paging in Gridview with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, paging

I know my types of various other issues are listed here in SO, but I think my issue is quite different from the existing one or mine approach is different.

I have a table call tblListing where there is 108 columns, in which i have 170000 records and increasing. In my admin section i am pulling out 20 columns. But the problem is the its taking more than a minute to display in gridview.

Earlier , i was using datatable to display the records, but the page and system became very sluggish. Now i applied LINQ, and is using .Take(20),but its displaying only 20 records.

So I want to load 20 records at a time, while paging.

Please help. Any sample code or refence will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really getting better performance using LINQ? LINQ is very useful, but it's not exactly known for performance.

Comment: @JamesJohnson That's a little misleading - LINQ doesn't inherently have worse performance that any other code that iterates over a collection. Of course, poorly written LINQ can have terrible performance - but so can a non-LINQ nested loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this article about [Paging With LINQ](http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/paging-with-linq.html) may be helpful for you:

Here's the relevant code:

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    //used by LINQ to SQL
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Page<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }

    //used by LINQ
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Page<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: I think this will answer the question, but you should include some of the relevant code snippets so your answer isn't entirely dependent on the availability of the link.